# Display your app at the top of a page

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, frontend

How do you achieve this ?

Here is my screenshot :
http://goo.gl/jC5xge

I have noticed that if you own the app the right button says Open and if you down own it , it will say View.

I have tried googling it but I have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a Smart App Banner. Information on how to [implement it here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).